# Submission token doesn't take key in Webform of Drupal 7, it takes value

Tags: drupal-7, token, submission, drupal-webform

i created a field with key and values.
"Field Key" is "element"

Options are:

1|Book

2|Pencil

Html of it is for example like this:

<-option value="1"->Book<-/option->

<-option value="2"->Pencil<-/option->

Then in "Form settings" i selected

"Custom URL" and paste this to this part

`content/answer-page?takeit=%value[element]`

But when i submit the form,

Resultant url is like this:

`content/answer-page?takeit=book`

But i want to pass "key" but form passes "value".

How can i get this as resultant url?

`content/answer-page?takeit=1`

Answer (score 1):

Wanted the same thing. Need the submitted key not the value.

All I've found so far is to grab the actual submission data via the sid...
http://drupal.org/node/236515#comment-5702416

Answer (score 0):

Update to tokens 4 branch.
Token 7.x-4 branch has tokens that can be used, e.g. [submission:values:field_1]